# Map array values to collection of items

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

How would one do the following elegantly with laravel collections ?

Map the values of the **$baseMap**  as keys to the collection.

The baseMap :

```
$baseMap = [
            'name' => 'new_name',
            'year' => 'new_year',
        ];
```

The collection :

```
 $items = collect([
            [
                'name' => 'name1',
                'year' => '1000',
                'not_in_basemap' => 'foo'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'name2',
                'year' => '2000',
                'not_in_basemap' => 'foo'
            ],
            //...
        ]);
```

The end result :

```
$result =[
            [
                'new_name' => 'name1',
                'new_year' => '1000',

            ],
            [
                'new_name'=> 'name2',
                'new_year' => '2000',

            ],
        ];
```

I know how to do it in plain php , just wondering what a nice collection version would be. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `only()` method. Not sure of the syntax but something like: `$result = $items->only($base_map);` You might have to make $base_map an array with `$items->only($base_map->toArray());`

Comment: @ourmandave : it is a start, but it will remove only the key not_in_baseMap , it will not replace the keys in the items to the values in baseMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @vivek_23 and @IndianCoding for giving me idea's I ended up with the following :
 I made a small edit to make sure the mapping and the items keys lined up.
 so you don't have to worry of misalignment and all in laravel collection !

```
$baseMap = collect($baseMap)->sortKeys();

$result = $items->map(function ($item) use ($baseMap) {

            return $baseMap->values()
                ->combine(
                    collect($item)->sortKeys()->intersectByKeys($baseMap)
                )
                ->all();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find collection methods, or php functions, but without success. Some dirty code that works with different keys from both sides (items and basemap).

```
$result = $items->map(function($item) use ($baseMap) {
    $array = [];

    foreach($baseMap as $oldKey => $newKey){
        if(isset($item[$oldKey])){
            $array[$newKey] = $item[$oldKey];
        }
    }

    return $array;
});

$result = $result->toArray();
```

Comment: Yes , I came to the same conclusion.  Plain old php it prob will be.   Thanks for your time mate !

Answer (score 2):

Use [intersectByKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-intersectbykeys) to filter your baseMap keys with `$items` values.

```
$result = $items->map(function($item,$key) use ($baseMap){
    return array_combine(array_values($baseMap),collect($item)->intersectByKeys($baseMap)->all());
});

dd($result);
```

**Update:**

In a pure collection way,

```
$baseMapCollect = collect($baseMap);

$result = $items->map(function($item,$key) use ($baseMapCollect){
    return $baseMapCollect->values()->combine(collect($item)->intersectByKeys($baseMapCollect->all())->values())->all();
});

dd($result);
```

Comment: First of you forgot the `use ($baseMapCollect)` in order to use the first collection in the closure, and second the result is not the expected one :)

Comment: @nakov Thanks, fixed that but apparently I can't test it.

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Well, I can't test. Can you let me know what exactly do you get as output?

Comment: No worries mate, thanks for your input !    Here your results Collection {#376 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "new_name"
      "year" => "new_year"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "new_name"
      "year" => "new_year"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder I have made an update. Could you test now and let me know?

Comment: sorry , it will still output the same array .. apart from removing the "not_in_basemap" key :  Collection {#374 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "name1"
      "year" => "1000"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "name2"
      "year" => "2000"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder The output seems to be same as you desired.

Comment: Look closely ...   The new key should be  new_name instead of name.

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Ohh.. I overlooked. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well done mate !   Interesting approach to it.  Thank you

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Happy to help :) I will update you with the same once I find something more in a pure collection way.

Comment: Yes, please do !

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Updated my answer via collections strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents, using `map`. Don't know how dynamic your collection should be, but knowing the keys I would do the following:

```
$baseMap = [
    'name' => 'new_name',
    'year' => 'new_year',
];

$items = collect([
    [
      'name' => 'name1',
      'year' => '1000',
      'not_in_basemap' => 'foo'
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'name2',
      'year' => '2000',
      'not_in_basemap' => 'foo'
    ],

  ])->map(function($item, $key) use ($baseMap) {
        return [
             $baseMap['name'] => $item['name'],
             $baseMap['year'] => $item['year']
        ];
  });
```

Comment: but by dynamic you mean only the content, or even the keys will change? Because this will work as long as the keys are `name` and `year` in both.

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes they will be dynamic...   Basemap will be set fixed as a class property . The rest will need to be dynamic...